# count results from query, show information according to result, refresh page using ajax to show information after button clicked

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to show this when there is questions to answer [questions](http://i347.photobucket.com/albums/p451/babyoth/questions.jpg)

and this when there is no questions to answer. [no questions](http://i347.photobucket.com/albums/p451/babyoth/noquestions.jpg)

This is a code I have tried using, the commented out lines are the if loop I tried but it always returned 1

```
<?php
        $dbtype = "mysql";
        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbname = "starsqa";
        $dbuser = "root";
        try {
            $pdo_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser);
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }

        $qry_string = "select * from questions inner join stars on stars.starID = questions.starID where stars.starID = ? && approved = 1 && answered = 1 && `check` = 0";
        $prep = $pdo_conn->prepare($qry_string);
        $starid = $_SESSION['starid'];
        $prep->execute(array($starid));
        //if (count($qry_string) > 0) {
            //echo count($qry_string);
            echo "<table style='border:0px; background-color:#8C7E6C;'><thead style='border:0px;'><tr style='border:0px solid white; background-color:#153E7E; color:white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><th style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>Question</th><th style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>Response</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
            while ($row = $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo "<tr style='border:1px white; background-color:lightblue; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><td style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>{$row['question']}</td>
                      <td style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><textarea rows='4' cols='50' id='{$row['questionID']}' class='response'>{$row['response']}</textarea></td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</tbody></table>";     
            echo "<br><button type='button' class='save_btn'>Save All</button><br><br>";
        //}
//        if (count($qry_string) < 1) {  
//          echo count($qry_string); 
//          echo "no question to answer atm"; 
//        }
        ?>
```

anyone got ideas on why this isn't working or another way to achieve this?

it's working now (thanks showdev) using this:

```
$prep->execute(array($starid));
//if (count($qry_string) > 0) {
    //echo count($qry_string);
        // $count= count($prep->fetchAll());    
         $count = $prep->rowCount();
         //echo "$count";
         if ($count > 0){
    echo "<table style='border:0px; background-color:#8C7E6C;'><thead style='border:0px;'><tr style='border:0px solid white; background-color:#153E7E; color:white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><th style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>Question</th><th style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>Response</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    while ($row = $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr style='border:1px white; background-color:lightblue; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><td style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>{$row['question']}</td>
              <td style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><textarea rows='4' cols='50' id='{$row['questionID']}' class='response'>{$row['response']}</textarea></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";     
    echo "<br><button type='button' class='save_btn'>Save All</button><br><br>";  

}
if ($count < 1) {  
  echo "no question to answer atm"; 
}
```

just thought of something else it needs once i press save all for ajax to refresh the page and show the new/current information, what function would i use to do this?

i did it :-) using this: location.reload();

```
var html = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".save_btn").live('click', function() {

        $('.response').each(function(){
            //alert($(this).attr('id'));
            //alert($(this).val());
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                html = $.ajax({
                    url: "response.php?questionID=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&response=" + $(this).val() + "&check=0",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;
            }   
            if ($(this).val() !== '') {
                html = $.ajax({
                    url: "response.php?questionID=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&response=" + $(this).val() + "&check=1",
                    async: false
                }).responseText;
            }   

        }); 
        alert(html);
        location.reload();
    });
})
```

Comment: Well done! Kudos for finding your own solution. You might consider using a form to post the data (unless you have a specific reason to use ajax). Just seems simpler.

Comment: it started off as a form but i changed it, when i decided ajax was better to use in this case (IMO anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are counting your query string rather than the resulting record set. Try `fetchAll` and count the results or try `rowCount`:

```
$count=count($prep->fetchAll(););
$count = $prep->rowCount();
```

From the documentation:

> [rowCount] is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

Comment: thanks working now :-) i edited the question to show how i edited the code

Comment: just thought of something else it needs once i press save all for ajax to refresh the page and show the new/current information, what function would i use to do this?

Comment: just needed one line of code, see above edited the question :-)